# Geometry data is coming instead of geometry

Tags: mesh, geometry

[image] I want to create a pipe from converging the plane vertices, then in the object properties its showing geometry data instead of geometry so that I can put the size of the bezier circle in it to make a pipe? why?(blender 2.9)

Comment: hello, you must be confusing between curves and meshes, Object Data > Geometry is for curves, Object Data > Geometry Data is for meshes. Are you trying to create a curve bevel?

Comment: Hi!!, thanks for answering,
I am trying to put the size of the bevel circle in a straight line with curve, so from a single curved line it gains a hollow structure in which the water can pass through

btw I am a total beginner so can you explain this briefly, I would be so greetfull

Thanks

Comment: hello, it's hard to understand, please show some pictures or even share your file (read the instructions): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I just added a picture so can you tell whats wrong in this? and sorry that is bezier circle, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have selected is not a curve, it's a mesh, you need to use a curve, or you can convert your mesh to a curve: Go in the header menu > *Object > Convert to > Curve from Mesh*:

[image]

Comment: thank you soo much bro,

<3